# WinForm deleting rows

Tags: sql, winforms

I have a DataGridView hooked up to a database and I am making the Delete command, how do I get it to delete a selected row? I want it to be something along the lines of:

DELETE FROM TableName
Where Id "is selected"

I want to delete the row the user has clicked on

Answer (score -1):

If you are 'hooked on', or connected to a database source, removing it from the GridView will remove it from the underlying table. At least in ListView it does.

If you need to manually delete the row, you can use the following query:

```
 "DELETE FROM table WHERE your_key_column = " + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]
```

This assumes you are sure that you have only one row selected and the first cell contains your key that uniquely defines the row to delete.

Comment: Well, it will, if it doesn't, then override the 'on delete' event.

Comment: The Update button throws an error which says I need a valid DeleteCommand, which is what I'm asking about. I want it to delete only the row that has been selected

Comment: Can you post the query. Could it be that it is not updateable, like a join query?

Comment: I can update everything after making changes to a row, it's just delete

Comment: Again, deleting SHOULD WORK. Try to post more information about your problem, because what I see here, it should work. My next guess would be: do you have DELETE privilege, and I guess you do... Also, post detailes of the exception you are getting

Comment: I need to sort out my Delete statement before anything will work

Comment: I need a WHERE statement in my DeleteCommand and I'm not sure what to put there, That's what I asked in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4913/discussion-between-jaredb-w-and-zmilojko)